# Javascript slow on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, d3.js, svg

Our company has a page that displays a number of complex SVG graphs with d3.js

We have noticed that for anyone using an Android mobile it takes a lot longer to initially display the graphs (compared to an iPhone with a similar cpu) and I have been tasked with optimising it.  Using the Chrome devtools performance profiler remotely connected to my Android (Galaxy A7 2017) I found that it appears to be the scripting taking all the time, there are no rendering issues.

As an example, one of the main culprits is adding tickvalues to each graph which when commented out speeds it up considerably:

```
minor_y_axis.tickValues(tick_array);
```

I really just want to know if this is a known Android problem, does javascript simply run slower?  Am I wasting my time trying to optimise this?

Comment: to determine if it is an "Android problem" as you say, have you tried different browsers on the Android?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the default Samsung browser and Chrome beta.

Comment: and what about Firefox?

Comment: Just tried Firefox, it's even slower...

Comment: ouch, I guess  Quantum hasn't made it to Android yet :p